# x265 cross compilation for arm

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, libx265

I tried to build [x265](https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265/) for arm using different variants of the following script

```
cmake -D CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME="Linux" -D CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=1 -D CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR="armv7" -D CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH="/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/"  -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc" -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE="-march=armv7-a" -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE="-march=armv7-a" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="arm-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$HOME/Desktop/armlibs/install_all/"  -DENABLE_SHARED:bool=on ../../source
```

But when I make this it gives this:

```
[  1%] Building CXX object encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/analysis.cpp.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++: error: unrecognized argument in option ‘-march=i686’
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++: note: valid arguments to ‘-march=’ are: armv2 armv2a armv3 armv3m armv4 armv4t armv5 armv5e armv5t armv5te armv6 armv6-m armv6j armv6k armv6s-m armv6t2 armv6z armv6zk armv7 armv7-a armv7-m armv7-r armv7e-m ep9312 iwmmxt iwmmxt2 native
make[2]: *** [encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/analysis.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [encoder/CMakeFiles/encoder.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is the problem here?

Update:

I just found this comment [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7743162.html?sid=7bf37f375391f2e3e817ea71f0ff6f01) : "X265 is not available on ARM. It looks like it's only available on X86." Is it true?

Comment: The error message indicates that the ARM compiler is being passed the `-march=i686`; i.e. being asked to compile i86 code.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo But I am setting C and CXX flags to armv7. What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, a brief look through the makefile [disproves the lack of ARM support](https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265/src/e951ab673b1c3d41ef86bc623f20ecc768d3f5c5/source/CMakeLists.txt?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#CMakeLists.txt-61)...

Comment: @Notlikethat Actually I tried with "armv6l" too. It gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this answer while researching how to cross compile x265 for a different arch. When the question was asked ARM wasn't supported but since version 2.0 released on July 2016, [armv6 and later support was added](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/master/releasenotes.html?highlight=arm#version-2-0)

I didn't personally try to cross compile to ARM, but I'd retry with the given command and setup.